# Simple chat program in Meteor. How do I hook up a callback to fire when new messages come in?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming

I'm working on this simple chat app to learn Meteor and I'm a little stuck here. I have a nicely working chatroom, but I'm having trouble hooking up a function to fire when a chat comes in from another person. I'd like to automatically scroll to the bottom of the window and update the favicon notification when this happens. I have a template `chatWindow` that looks like this:

```
<template name="chatWindow">
    <div class="textWindow">
        {{#each messages}}
            <span class="username {{#if me}}me{{/if}}">{{username}}</span><span class="message">{{message}}</span>
            <br />
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <br />
    <form>
        {{#if currentUser}}
            <input type="text" name="chatTextBox" id="chatTextBox" />
        {{/if}}
    </form>
</template>
```

The `{{#each messages}}` block works great for grabbing the updated collection of chat messages automatically, but how do I fire an event when it's updated? I've tried `Template.chatWindow.onRender()` and `Template.chatWindow.rendered` but they both only fire the first time.

Comment: How is `messages` stored?

Comment: They're a helper that retrieves them through a published collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe is usually the way to go here. Assuming `messages` are stored in a collection `Messages`, you can do something like:

```
Messages.find().observe({
  added: function (document) {
    // Set some Session vars or do some jquery or update other collections
  }
});
```

Observe works on both the client and server, and can also register callbacks for document `changed` events and document `removed` events.

Comment: That's the missing piece I was looking for, thank you!